# Python: Cannot send socket data as mail

Tags: python, sockets, smtplib

please I am trying to sending data gotten from a socket connection through mail in same program. I created a function to send the mail and tried calling the function from a while loop and after the connection receives the data it just stays there till the program crash,. please see my noob code below : (

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib


ip_address = '127.0.0.1'
port = 7989
time = datetime.now()

def email():
    smtp_server = 'smtp.smtpserver.com'
    smtpuser = 'admin@smtpserver.com'
    smtp_pass = 'passsword'

    from_name = "sender name"
    receipient = ['user@userdomain.com', 'user1@userdomain.com']
    subject = 'New incoming mail'
    host_and_key = ''

    message = f"""\
    From: {from_name}
    To: {receipient}
    Subject: {subject}\n
    {host_and_key}
    """
    mailer = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, 465)
    mailer.starttls()
    try:
        mailer.login(smtpuser,smtp_pass)
        print("Logged in...")
        mailer.sendmail(from_name, receipient, message)
        print(f"Email sent! to {receipient}")
        smtp_server.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Something went wrong….", ex)


# connect to server to get hostname and key


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((ip_address, port))
    print(f'server listening on port: {port}')
    while 1> 0:
        s.listen(10)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(f'connection from {addr} accepted')
        with conn:
            while True:
                host_and_key = conn.recv(2084).decode()
                email()
                with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(host_and_key + '\n')
                    break
                    print('connection completed and closed!')
```

It stays on print(f'connection from {addr} accepted') for a while then gives below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 50, in <module>
    email()
  File "server.py", line 25, in results
    mailer = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, 465)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: You want `mailer.close()`, not `smtp_server.close`.  `smtp_server` is just a string.  It doesn't have a `close` method.

Comment: However, there's a more serious problem.  An "f" string is evaluated at the point where it is created.  So, your `message` will ALWAYS have the default contents, including an empty `{host_and_key}`.  If you're going to use an "f" string, you'll need to move that into the function.

Comment: Tell us more about the "crash". Do you get an exception?

Comment: @TimRoberts I corrected the mailer.close() line and moved the message variable inside the email function but I am still getting error. I updated my question.

Comment: @DarkKnight I updated the question with error message.

Comment: Which of your lines of code is line 50? Given that the exception is clearly not being caught in your try/except block, it must be happening either during construction of the SMTP class (most likely) or starttls()